# On CloseReason.UserClosing form is showing dialog for close 2 times

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show dialog when user is trying to close app(red windows cross and button on my form) but when windows is shutting down, this dialog blocking the shutdown, so I wan to want detect by app when is windows shutting down and proceed without dialog. Here is my code

after form load Im catching close event:

```
this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
```

and

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.CloseReason)
        {
            case CloseReason.UserClosing:
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit the application?", "Your App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                    }
                break;
            case CloseReason.WindowsShutDown:
                e.Cancel = false; //this is propably dumb
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when user is closing app, dialog is shown 2 times. First dialog dotn do anything, action is taken after second dialog.
How can I show dialog for closing only once and no dialog when windows is shutting down(because windows is waiting for my app to close)?

Comment: Check your call stack and see where the Close() call is coming from. Or make sure you have not subscribed to the event twice?

Comment: I tries to debug it,but it just getting fired second time just after clicking to yes or no in the dialog

Comment: Try commenting out your `this.FormClosing += new ...` code.  You probably have it subscribed through the designer already (or just check the designer file).

Comment: @LarsTech That would be my guess as well.  A lot of these events get auto-subscribed by the VS Engine in the partial class that gets stored in the Class.Designer.cs file.  Check that one to make sure that there isn't already a subscription to the event.

Comment: @Nevyn The better way to do this is to not subscribe to any form events and just write this code in the `OnFormClosing` override.

Comment: yes,removing that event catch helped,thx!:) if you want add this as answer and I select it as right one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way to write this code (my opinion) is to not subscribe to the form events, but to use the available override method:

```
protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  switch (e.CloseReason)
  {
    case CloseReason.UserClosing:
      if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to exit the application?", "Your App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
      {
        e.Cancel = true;
      }
      break;
    case CloseReason.WindowsShutDown:
      e.Cancel = false; //this is propably dumb
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

  base.OnFormClosing(e);
}
```

You might want to consider using just an `if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)` instead of the switch statement based on its current form.  `e.Cancel` is already False by default so you do not need to exclicitly set it.

Comment: `private override` probably isn't what you meant, and generally, when overriding a virtual function, you should call the base method as well.

Comment: Do avoid making it an opinion.  It is a fact that overriding OnFormClosing() is the proper way to do this ;)